# Appsync Authorization for Non Signed In Users

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

Im using Appsync in a Vue application and have Cognito user pools setup for users to be able to sign-in to my application. However, there are some pages on my app where a non-signed in user should be able to view only ie: "think: reading answers on stack overflow" , however there are some cases where users need to be able to add a comment to that page and need to sign in to edit it.

On my API in Appsync I have the authorization set to  "Amazon Cognito User Pool" and the default action set to "Allow" but then how can I make it so non-cognito users can still view a page? What combination of settings should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annoyingly AppSync does not support multiple authentication methods, and as you've noticed Cognito UserPool integration requires users to have signed in before they can access the graphql endpoint.

There are a few workarounds, however none of them are that pretty:

- Deploy two versions- one with full functionality using UserPools and one open version using API Key (that you embed into the client)
- Handle authentication yourself. Use the IAM Role security for App Sync, and instead of connecting directly to the graphql endpoint, create a proxy lambda in API Gateway that either verifies UserPool users or allows limited access with no credentials.
- Create a no-user "user" in your UserPool with *known* (e.g. in your app, or from an endpoint) credentials. The onus would then be on you to check if your user is *this* user when responding to secured mutations/queries. One way of doing this more safely might be to add a custom attribute "custom:insecure" which you can check for on non-open endpoints.
- Use the "viewer" pattern (check Facebook's implementation). Make your GraphQL Schema open by default (e.g. known API Key) and have all of your queries/mutations take the first parameter of `viewer`. This might be the access token that Cognito returns on authentication. Each resolver would then be responsible for determining if the token is valid (e.g.`cognito::getUser`) or access is allowed without a `viewer` defined.

Although it initially sounds like the hardest, I would recommend my first solution. There are ways of automating AppSync deployments, and it makes a *clear distiniction* between what's open and what's secured on your schema.